# Installing pgAdmin on Ubuntu - not working

Tags: python, postgresql, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, pgadmin-4

I wanted to install PGAdmin on my Ubuntu 16.04.  I used the following steps from a youtube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p6_aDUMVsug):

**Install virtual environment and required packages:**

```
 1) sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev libgmp3-dev
 2) sudo apt-get install virtualenv python-pip libpq-dev python-dev
 3) cd opt
 4) mkdir environmentpy
 5) cd environmentpy
 6  virtualenv pgadmin4
 7) cd pgadmin4
 8) source bin/activate
```

**Download and install PGadmin4:**

```
9) wget https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v1.3/pip/pgadmin4-1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
10) sudo pip install pgadmin4-1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
11) cd lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4
12) touch config_local.py
```

**Configuration:**

```
13) echo “SERVER_MODE = False” >> /lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/config_local.py
14) python pgAdmin4.py
```

Apparently something went wrong around step 9 or 10 because when I tried to change dir, like step 11, it said "No such file or directory" (which is true).

Some errors are:

A) flask-babel 0.11.1 has requirement Babel>=2.3, but you'll have babel 1.3 which is incompatible.

B) testtools 2.3.0 has requirement extras>=1.0.0, but you'll have extras 0.0.3 which is incompatible.

**After running 'pip install pgadmin4-1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl' :**

C) Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/environmentpy/pgadmin4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytz-2014.10.dist-info'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

For error C, I used sudo which gives me:

The directory '/home/user/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/user/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement 'pgadmin4-1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist.

I have tried other ways to fix it too, but I know is already a large explanation. I just want to have PGAdmin installed correctly and working.  If someone know an efficient way to do it, I will appreciate the help.  If I have to un-install and install again in a different way, please let me know the steps.

Answer (score 0):

Use these following commands, this will solve the error:

sudo apt-get install postgresql

sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2

sudo apt-get install libpq-dev

A)For error: flask-babel 0.11.1 has requirement Babel>=2.3, but you'll have babel 1.3 which is incompatible.

pip install flask-htmlmin

For Error: testtools 2.3.0 has requirement extras>=1.0.0, but you'll have extras 0.0.3 which is incompatible.

enter:

wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/03/e9/e915af1f97914cd0bc21e125fd1bfd4106de614a275e4b6866d9ac/extras-1.00-py2.py3-none-any.whl